# Unpickling python2 datetime under python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, compatibility, pickle

I chose to use pickle (+base64+TCP sockets) to communicate data between my python3 code and legacy python2 code, but I am having trouble with `datetime` objects:

The PY3 object unpickles well on PY2, but the reverse raises a `TypeError` when calling the datetime constructor, then a `UnicodeEncodeError` in the load_reduce function.

A short test program & the log, including dis output of both PY2 and PY3 pickles, are available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/191f15871c1b9f801b76)

- I am using `pickle.dumps(reply, protocol=2)` in PY2 
  then `pickle._loads(pickled, fix_imports=True, encoding='latin1')` in PY3
   (tried None and utf-8 without success)
- Native cPickle `loads` decoding fails too, I am only using pure python's `_loads` for debugging.

Is this a `datetime` bug ? Maybe `datetime.__getstate__/__setstate__` implementations are not compatible ?

Any remark on the code is welcome...

### Complement

PY-3.4.0 pickle:

```
 0: \x80 PROTO      2
 2: c    GLOBAL     'datetime datetime'
21: q    BINPUT     0
23: c    GLOBAL     '_codecs encode'
39: q    BINPUT     1
41: X    BINUNICODE u'\x07\xde\x07\x11\x0f\x06\x11\x05\n\x90'
58: q    BINPUT     2
60: X    BINUNICODE u'latin1'
71: q    BINPUT     3
73: \x86 TUPLE2
74: q    BINPUT     4
76: R    REDUCE
77: q    BINPUT     5
79: \x85 TUPLE1
80: q    BINPUT     6
82: R    REDUCE
83: q    BINPUT     7
85: .    STOP
```

PY-2.7.6 pickle:

```
 0: \\x80 PROTO      2
 2: c    GLOBAL     'datetime datetime'
21: q    BINPUT     0
23: U    SHORT_BINSTRING '\\x07\xc3\x9e\\x07\\x11\\x0f\\x06\\x11\\x05\\n\\x90'
35: q    BINPUT     1
37: \\x85 TUPLE1
38: q    BINPUT     2
40: R    REDUCE
41: q    BINPUT     3
43: ]    EMPTY_LIST
44: q    BINPUT     4
46: N    NONE
47: \\x87 TUPLE3
48: q    BINPUT     5
50: .    STOP
```

PY-3.4.0 `pickle.load_reduce`:

```
def load_reduce(self):
    stack = self.stack
    args = stack.pop()
    func = stack[-1]
    try:
        value = func(*args)
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
        print(func, args)
        raise
    stack[-1] = value
dispatch[REDUCE[0]] = load_reduce
```

PY-3.4.0 `datetime` pickle support:

```
# Pickle support.

def _getstate(self):
    yhi, ylo = divmod(self._year, 256)
    us2, us3 = divmod(self._microsecond, 256)
    us1, us2 = divmod(us2, 256)
    basestate = bytes([yhi, ylo, self._month, self._day,
                       self._hour, self._minute, self._second,
                       us1, us2, us3])
    if self._tzinfo is None:
        return (basestate,)
    else:
        return (basestate, self._tzinfo)

def __setstate(self, string, tzinfo):
    (yhi, ylo, self._month, self._day, self._hour,
     self._minute, self._second, us1, us2, us3) = string
    self._year = yhi * 256 + ylo
    self._microsecond = (((us1 << 8) | us2) << 8) | us3
    if tzinfo is None or isinstance(tzinfo, _tzinfo_class):
        self._tzinfo = tzinfo
    else:
        raise TypeError("bad tzinfo state arg %r" % tzinfo)

def __reduce__(self):
    return (self.__class__, self._getstate())
```

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but pickle is not meant, in general, for data exchange between different version or long-term storage. Is there an unambiguous format (text?) you could use?

Comment: If you simply want to keep the information of datetime, I suggest you pickle the formatted text of the datetime, unpickle it somewhere else and parse the string into datetime again.

Comment: @JimmyK The initial goal was having a flexible solution (i.e. not having to hard-code conversion each time the object changes) without resorting to eternal packages like pyro...

Comment: @mdurant Given the `fix_imports` option of Unpickler (and the backwards-compatible protocols), you'd think they planned for a cross-version solution ;-)

Comment: @eddygeek - how did you produce "PY-3.4.0 pickle" dis?

Comment: Never mind.  Such pickle is produced in 3.x when pickle.dump() is called with protocol=2.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to use the `encoding="bytes"` like this:

```
pickled_bytes = bytes(pickled_str, encoding='latin1')  # If your input is a string(not my case)
data = pickle.loads(pickled_bytes, encoding='bytes')
```

(Thanks to Tim Peters for the suggestion)

Issue still opened at http://bugs.python.org/issue22005 as to why this is required.

Comment: Nice... as long as you're not stuck on Cygwin's Python 3.2, which doesn't seem to know about encoding='bytes'. Argh.

Comment: It should be noted that this issue is "fixed" in the most recent versions of Python 3. However, you must still remember to use `encoding='latin-1'` when unpickling on Python 3. I find this unintuitive and not all that much better than `encoding='bytes'`, because to me, it is not obvious that `datetime` would involve strings at all. And if your Python 2 pickle contains both datetimes as well as *encoded* strings in encodings other than Latin-1, then you're back to having to use `bytes` anyway.