# UnicodeDecodeError in pickle.load

Tags: windows-7, pickle, python-3.5, non-ascii-characters

I'm having some problems with loading a pkl file using pickle. I'm using windows 7 and Python 3.5.1 64 bit. The pkl file was downloaded from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/lasagne/recipes/pretrained/imagenet/vgg16.pkl).

This is my code:

```
import pickle

# Load model weights and metadata
weightFile = open('vgg16.pkl', 'rb')
d = pickle.load(weightFile)
```

and when I run it I get the output

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" C:/work/lasagne/tutorial/lasagne-tutorial2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/work/lasagne/tutorial/lasagne-tutorial2.py", line 5, in <module>
    d = pickle.load(weightFile)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What does this error message mean? It says that there is a byte that the acsii codec can't decode, but isn't a pkl file supposed to be binary (hence not contain ascii characters)?

Am I doing something wrong when loading the file? What can I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218598/1070480). The pickle file was probably encoded with Python 2, and providing `pickle.load` with the optional argument `encoding='latin1'` solved the problem.

The code that works looks like this:

```
import pickle

# Load model weights and metadata
weightFile = open('vgg16.pkl', 'rb')
d = pickle.load(weightFile, encoding='latin1')
```