# check pickle protocol of pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I learned that in python3 there are 5 diferent protocols for a pickle file ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41284318/4391129)).
I wonder how to get meta-data-information (especialy the protocol) from a pickle-file.

Answer (score 2):

based on the [pickle source in Python 3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pickle.py) and a bit of experimentation it's pretty easy to get to version numbers 2 and above by looking at the first 2 bytes.  the first is documented as:

```
PROTO          = b'\x80'  # identify pickle protocol
```

in the above file, and can be tested with:

```
' '.join(f'{c:02x}' for c in pickle.dumps(42, protocol=2))
```

which gives me:

> 80 02 4b 2a 2e

i.e. a byte (0x80) which says we're about to get a version number, then the version number 2.  if we run it with more recent version numbers it changes appropriately, i.e. version 5 gives:

> 80 05 4b 2a 2e

which looks easy enough.  lower version numbers don't seem to report anything, but maybe somebody else will suggest something!