# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 5

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a file using the following code.

```
precomputed = pickle.load(open('test/vgg16_features.p', 'rb'))
features = precomputed['features']
```

But getting this error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The file I am trying to read contains image features which are extracted using deep neural networks. The file content looks like below.

```
(dp0
S'imageIds'
p1
(lp2
I262145
aI131074
aI131075
aI393221
aI393223
aI393224
aI524297
aI393227
aI393228
aI262146
aI393230
aI262159
aI524291
aI322975
aI131093
aI524311
....
....
....
```

Please note that, this is big file, of size 2.8GBs.

I know this is a duplicate question but I followed the suggested solutions in other stackoverflow posts but couldn't solve it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The problem was actually about [unpickling a python 2 object with python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3/28218598#28218598) which I couldn't understand first because the pickle file I got was written through a python 2 program.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218598/5352399) which solved the problem. So, all I need to do is set the `encoding` parameter of `pickle.load()` function to `latin1` because `latin1` works for any input as it maps the byte values 0-255 to the first 256 Unicode codepoints directly.

So, the following worked for me!

```
precomputed = pickle.load(open('test/vgg16_features.p', 'rb'), encoding='latin1')
```