# unpickle a python 2 object in python 3 raises ValueError

Tags: python, pickle

In python 2.7.6:

```
# the data i'm trying to pickle
>>> x[0:5]
[494.12804680901604, 641.9374923706055, 778.293918918919, 470.2265625, 237.21332017010934]
>>> y[0:5]
[236.99996948242188, 381.6793310733242, 685.0, 409.0909090909091, 658.0]
>>> z[0:5]
[23, 20, 98, 24, 78]
>>> holder = [x,y,z]
```

How i'm pickling:

```
with open('holderData.obj','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(holder,f)
f.close()
```

In python 3.6.2

```
with open('holderData.obj','rb') as f:
     d = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
```

Yet, this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

The only question/answer I could found related to [this issue, tells me to add the `encoding='bytes'` bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3) which doesn't work in this instance.

The pickle itself `print(repr(pickle.dumps(holder)))`:

```
'(lp0\n(lp1\nF494.12804680901604\naF641.9374923706055\naF778.293918918919\naF470.2265625\naF237.21332017010934\naF372.76081123737373\naF396.15337968952133\naF615.2265625\naF470.2265625\naF581.2155330882352\naF488.40675200803213\naF475.47189597315435\naF92.0511279585
```

Comment: See the **Data stream formats (protocols)** section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence/4529901#4529901) to another question.

Comment: Can you show the pickle itself (i.e., the result of `print(repr(pickle.dumps(holder)))`? And what are the Python types of `x`, `y` and `z`? (They *look* like lists, but it's not 100% clear.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Added the pickle itself. `x`,`y`,and `z` are all lists, each a little under 3000 in length.

Comment: @martineau Setting it to highest priority did the trick.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce this at all. Are you sure there's nothing weird in the lists after index 4?

Comment: Mitchell: It might be better to find a literal numeric value that works in both versions instead of `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` (or `-1`). Chose the largest number that works in both. Being explicit will protect you from it changing if (when) you upgrade either one to later version (and it breaking your code).

Comment: @martineau: The protocol shouldn't matter, though: Python 3 can read any pickle protocol that Python 2 can write.

Comment: @Mark: True. I was mistakenly thinking of bi-directional compatibility, not just Py2 → Py3 (the subject of this question).