# Read a *.dat file in python from a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, dataset

I'm trying to read a .dat file from the DEAP dataset (http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/mmv/datasets/deap/readme.html)
however when using the pickle module, this error occures:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and this is the simple code: `dataset = pc.load(open('dataset/s01.dat','rb'))`

so my question is:
 1. How can I read it?
2. which module should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpickling a python 2 object with python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import pickle    
with open('dataset/s01.dat', 'rb') as f:
    x = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```