# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when opening Python 2 Pickle file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to open a pickle file in Python 3 with code that worked in Python 2 but is now giving me an error. Here is the code:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    d = pickle.load(f)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-38f711abef06> in <module>()
      1 with open(file, 'r') as f:
----> 2     d = pickle.load(f)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I saw on other SO answers that people had this problem when using `open(file ,'rb')` and switching to `open(file ,'r')` fixed it. If this helps, I tried `open(file ,'rb')` just to experiment and got the following error:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b77842748a06> in <module>()
      1 with open(file, 'rb') as f:
----> 2     d = pickle.load(f)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.
```

When I open the file with `f = open(file, 'r')` and the enter `f` I get:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/LargeDataSets/Enron/final_project_dataset.pkl' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

So I also tried:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    d = pickle.load(f, encoding='cp1252')
```

and got the same error as with using 'rb':

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-959b1b0496d0> in <module>()
      1 with open(file, 'rb') as f:
----> 2     d = pickle.load(f, encoding='cp1252')

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After digging through the raw file in Sublime, it looks like the file was not correctly pickled. The above code works perfectly on a different version of that file.

Answer (score 15):

Explanation for loading with encoding = bytes.

Assume you have a dictionary to be pickled in Python2

```
data_dict= {'key1': value1, 'key2': value2}
with open('pickledObj.pkl', 'wb') as outfile:
  pickle.dump(data_dict, outfile)
```

Unpickling in Python3

```
with open('pickledObj.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        data_dict = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
```

Note: The keys of dictionary are not strings anymore. They are bytes.

```
data_dict['key1'] #result in KeyError

data_dict[b'key1'] #gives value1
```

or use

```
data_dict['key1'.encode('utf-8')] #gives value1
```

Comment: This also makes *value* strings into bytes! how do you take care of them for backward compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there are some changes between the Python 2 and 3 pickle formats. If possible, I'd recommend creating the pickled data again using Python 3.

If that's not possible/easy, try playing with different encoding settings (did you try `'utf8'`?) or reading the data in with `encoding='bytes'` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3) and then decoding the strings in your code where you can inspect the object further.