# Passing a python object from a python2 script to python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I ran into an issue where my current traffic generator: Warp17 has generated python code that is only python2 compatible. We are moving all else to python3 so i have created a cli tool that wraps our warp17 api. Is there a better way to pass information from a subscript than just printing the output and loading it in json?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import python2_api

if __name__ == "__main__":
  do_some_argparse()
  result = dict(run_some_code_on_args())
  print(result)
```

```
def run_warp_cli(*args):
  result = subprocess.Popen('warp_cli', args)
  return json.loads(result)
```

This is basically what I am doing. I was curious if there was any interesting way to avoid doing this and get back an actual python dictionary object etc.

Comment: Probably not. You can only transfer the data in the dictionary, not the structure itself, since the implementations of dict are different in ABI between python 2 and 3. Serialization, whether to JASON or some other mutually agreeable format seems like a good way to do that.

Comment: Is there a way to maybe load a python2 pickle into python3?

Comment: That would be essentially the same thing, just a slightly different storage format is all. It's probably possible since I doubt that `dict` would ever pickle the actual hash table: hash values change between runs even of the same interpreter.

Comment: Yes you can, although you have to be careful with data types that changed between versions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28218466/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary representation of dictionaries, and in fact objects in general, has changed quite a bit between Python 2 and Python 3. That means that you will not be able to use the objects directly between versions of Python. Some form of serialization to a mutually acceptable format will be necessary.

The JSON format you are using fits this criterion. I would recommend sticking with it as it is flexible, human readable and quite general.

If space becomes an issue, you can look into pickling as an alternative, but I would not recommend it as a first choice. While [`pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) can understand Python 2 data just fine, there are many caveats to keep in mind with different interpretations of datatypes between Python versions, especially `bytes`: [Unpickling a python 2 object with python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28218466/2988730)

Here is a resource that may help you with some common errors from unpicking on the Python 3 side: [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when opening Python 2 Pickle file in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46001958/2988730)