# How to read a ckpt file with python3, while it is saved using python2？

Tags: python, pytorch

I try to read a checkpoint file with pyTorch

```
checkpoint = torch.load(xxx.ckpt)
```

The file was generated by a program written using python 2.7. I try to read the file using python 3.6 but get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is it possible to read the file without downgrade python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I solve the issue by

1) create a python2 environment using anaconda

2) read the checkpoint file using `pytorch`, and then save it using `pickle`

```
checkpoint = torch.load("xxx.ckpt")
with open("xxx.pkl", "wb") as outfile:
    pickle.dump(checkpointfile, outfile)
```

3) back to the python3 environment, read the file using `pickle`, save the file using `pytorch`

```
pkl_file = open("xxx.pkl", "rb")
data = pickle.load(pkl_file, encoding="latin1")
torch.save(data, "xxx.ckpt")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some compatibility issues in `pickle` between Python 2.x and Python 3.x, because of the move to unicode, you're probably saving a string as part of your model and that's why you see that error.

You can follow the recommended way to save a model in Pytorch and do:

```
torch.save(filename, model.state_dict())
```

instead of saving `model`. Then in Python3:

```
model = Model() # construct a new model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(filename))
```

Another way is to unpickle in Python 2 and save it to another format that is easier to transfer between Python 2 and Python 3. For example you can save the tensors of the architecture using the Pytorch-Numpy bridge and use `np.savez`.

You can also try to use `pickle` instead of `torch.load` and [tell it to decode ASCII strings to Python3 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3)

Comment: Well, `pickle` doesn't work. It just generate an integer.

Comment: can you provide the code for the model you're saving and how you're saving it? I have a hard time debugging something I can't reproduce