# How to convert pickle.loads from Python 2 to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pickle

I am trying to convert a Python 2 code into Python 3. I used the `pickle.loads` function in Python 2.7, which according to its documentation does the following (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html):

```
pickle.loads(string)
Read a pickled object hierarchy from a string. Characters in the 
string past the pickled object’s representation are ignored.
```

However its behavior changes in Python 3 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

```
pickle.loads(bytes_object, *, fix_imports=True, encoding="ASCII", errors="strict")
Read a pickled object hierarchy from a bytes object and return the 
reconstituted object hierarchy specified therein.
```

In the database, I have a string `x` which was the output of `pickle.dumps(obj)` performed in Python 2. I want to retrieve `obj` in Python 3. When I do `pickle.loads(x)`, I receive the following error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Changing `pickle.loads(x)` into `pickle.loads(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))` instead gives the following error:

```
invalid load key, '\x5c'.
```

How can I obtain `obj` from `x` in Python 3?

Comment: If you're trying to read a pickle created by Python 2 into Python 3, you need to set the right protocol: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format

Comment: [This article](https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/convert-py2-pickles-to-py3/) outlines the entire process by which one would do this, including gotchas.

Comment: @jonrsharpe according to its documentation: The protocol version of the pickle is detected automatically, so no protocol argument is needed. Is it still necessary to explicitly set the protocol when I call python.loads?

Comment: @alec_a The article talks mostly about `pickle.load` instead of `pickle.loads`. I couldn't resolve my problem by trying a similar fix for `pickle.loads`.

Comment: http://blog.yannisassael.com/2016/03/open-python-2-pickle-python-3/

Comment: @alec_a the string `x` in my scenario is retrieved from the database instead of from a file. I don't know how to use `pickle.load` in place of `pickle.loads`. Setting the encoding to latin1 does not resolve my issue, and I still receive the `invalid load key, '\x5c'` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `pickle.loads(x)` to `pickle.loads(bytes(x, 'latin-1'))`.

Change `pickle.dumps(o)` to `str(pickle.dumps(o, protocol=0), 'latin-1')`.

Comment: Or leveraging the internal of python,  passing the `encode` arg would do it.

`pickle.load(x, encoding='latin1')`

Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3