# Unpickling a file with python 3 that was pickled in python 2

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm running a code written in python 2 (not sure the exact version) using python 3.6. I'm having difficulties unpickling a file in python 3 that was pickled in python 2.

I have tried solutions given in similar questions using joblib.load, but that doesnt work for python 3 either. I have also included the encoding=latin1 but still didnt work.

```
with open('final_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

print("Loading other information...")

with open('final_tfidf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    tf_vectorizer = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
with open('final_idf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    idf_vector = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
with open('final_pos.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    pos_vectorizer = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

the error message is:
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.

and it points to the first pickle.load statement: 
 model = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

Comment: Try removing the `, encoding='latin1'` from that line

Comment: I did that, it didn't affect it. Still the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3

Comment: yes, a duplicate but the solutions given there didnt work for me.

Comment: Can you verify that the pickle loads correctly in Python 2?

Comment: Tried to do verify if it loads in Python 2 but encountered others errors, so I decided to start afresh in python 3. Thanks