# Cannot read pickled file using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, file, sqlalchemy, pickle

I have a pickle file crated using old versions of python 2 and SQLAlchemy (1.0.14), which is a mysql database template.

To read the file I used this script:

```
import pickle
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.reflection import Inspector

template_path = os.path.join( os. getcwd(), 'mysqldb_file')
with open(template_path, "rb") as file:
    src_tables = pickle.load(file)
```

when I run the script, I got this error:

```
src_tables = pickle.load(file)
```

File "C:\Users\MEGAPC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 1328, in **setstate**
object.**setattr**(self, "_index", state["_index"])

KeyError: '_index'

I uploaded the template file in google drive if someone want to test it.

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X_ljq-l4yIQ2X5IhLLlXXcw-5ElkgSP-/view?usp=sharing)

I don't have any experience with databases and sqlalchemy. Could someone help me to resolve this problem?
Thank you so much.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28218466/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson unfortunately adding encoding='latin1' or encoding='bytes' does not resolve the problem. This issue is related to SqlAlchemy