# Porting pickle py2 to py3 strings become bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle, python-3.6

I have a pickle file that was created with python 2.7 that I'm trying to port to python 3.6. The file is saved in py 2.7 via `pickle.dumps(self.saved_objects, -1)`

and loaded in python 3.6 via `loads(data, encoding="bytes")` (from a file opened in `rb` mode). If I try opening in `r` mode and pass `encoding=latin1` to `loads` I get UnicodeDecode errors. When I open it as a byte stream it loads, but literally every string is now a byte string. Every object's `__dict__` keys are all `b"a_variable_name"` which then generates attribute errors when calling `an_object.a_variable_name` because `__getattr__` passes a string and `__dict__` only contains bytes. I feel like I've tried every combination of arguments and pickle protocols already. Apart from forcibly converting all objects' `__dict__` keys to strings I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

** **Skip to 4/28/17 update for better example**

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

** **Update 4/27/17**

This minimum example illustrates my problem:

**From py 2.7.13**

```
import pickle

class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = u"test ¢" # including a unicode str breaks things

t = test()
dumpstr = pickle.dumps(t)

>>> dumpstr
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\ntest\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'x'\np6\nVtest \xa2\np7\nsb."
```

**From py 3.6.1**

```
import pickle

class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "xyz"

dumpstr = b"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\ntest\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'x'\np6\nVtest \xa2\np7\nsb."

t = pickle.loads(dumpstr, encoding="bytes")

>>> t
<__main__.test object at 0x040E3DF0>
>>> t.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    t.x
AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> t.__dict__
{b'x': 'test ¢'} 
>>>
```

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Update 4/28/17**

To re-create my issue I'm posting my actual raw pickle data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qazbnorjgxu6q6r/raw_data.pkl?dl=1)

The pickle file was created in python 2.7.13, windows 10 using

```
with open("raw_data.pkl", "wb") as fileobj:
    pickle.dump(library, fileobj, protocol=0)
```

(protocol 0 so it's human readable)

To run it you'll need `classes.py`

```
# classes.py

class Library(object): pass


class Book(object): pass


class Student(object): pass


class RentalDetails(object): pass
```

And the test script here:

```
# load_pickle.py
import pickle, sys, itertools, os

raw_pkl = "raw_data.pkl"
is_py3 = sys.version_info.major == 3

read_modes = ["rb"]
encodings = ["bytes", "utf-8", "latin-1"]
fix_imports_choices = [True, False]
files = ["raw_data_%s.pkl" % x for x in range(3)]


def py2_test():
    with open(raw_pkl, "rb") as fileobj:
        loaded_object = pickle.load(fileobj)
        print("library dict: %s" % (loaded_object.__dict__.keys()))
        return loaded_object


def py2_dumps():
    library = py2_test()
    for protcol, path in enumerate(files):
        print("dumping library to %s, protocol=%s" % (path, protcol))
        with open(path, "wb") as writeobj:
            pickle.dump(library, writeobj, protocol=protcol)


def py3_test():
    # this test iterates over the different options trying to load
    # the data pickled with py2 into a py3 environment
    print("starting py3 test")
    for (read_mode, encoding, fix_import, path) in itertools.product(read_modes, encodings, fix_imports_choices, files):
        py3_load(path, read_mode=read_mode, fix_imports=fix_import, encoding=encoding)


def py3_load(path, read_mode, fix_imports, encoding):
    from traceback import print_exc
    print("-" * 50)
    print("path=%s, read_mode = %s fix_imports = %s, encoding = %s" % (path, read_mode, fix_imports, encoding))
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print("start this file with py2 first")
        return
    try:
        with open(path, read_mode) as fileobj:
            loaded_object = pickle.load(fileobj, fix_imports=fix_imports, encoding=encoding)
            # print the object's __dict__
            print("library dict: %s" % (loaded_object.__dict__.keys()))
            # consider the test a failure if any member attributes are saved as bytes
            test_passed = not any((isinstance(k, bytes) for k in loaded_object.__dict__.keys()))
            print("Test %s" % ("Passed!" if test_passed else "Failed"))
    except Exception:
        print_exc()
        print("Test Failed")
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    print("-" * 50)


if is_py3:
    py3_test()
else:
    # py2_test()
    py2_dumps()
```

put all 3 in the same directory and run `c:\python27\python load_pickle.py` first which will create 1 pickle file for each of the 3 protocols. Then run the same command with python 3 and notice that it version converts the `__dict__`  keys to bytes. I had it working for about 6 hours, but for the life of me I can't figure out how I broke it again.

Comment: Have you tried utf-8?

Comment: yeah, ut8, utf16, latin1,, cp

Comment: If your pickle is in a file, why are you using `loads` instead of `load`?

Comment: I've tried it with both, `loads` just creates a BytesIO object and calls `load`

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example with an actual object that you pickle and then fail to unpickle?  I just tried a simple test and was able to successfully pickle a simple object with some attributes in Python 2 and then unpickle it in Python 3.

Comment: sure, my first 2 tries worked fine. I'll try to re-create it

Comment: @BrenBarn added a minimum working example

Comment: Your example works for me if I use `"utf-8"` or `"latin-1"` as the encoding when unpickling.

Comment: I see that, I'll make a more accurate minimum example. I think I have characters saved within my objects that can't be decoded with latin-1 or utf-8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, you're hitting [bug 22005](http://bugs.python.org/issue22005) with `datetime.date` objects in the `RentalDetails` objects.

That can be worked around with the `encoding='bytes'` parameter, but that leaves your classes with `__dict__` containing bytes:

```
>>> library = pickle.loads(pickle_data, encoding='bytes')
>>> dir(library)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'bytes'
```

It's possible to manually fix that based on your specific data:

```
def fix_object(obj):
    """Decode obj.__dict__ containing bytes keys"""
    obj.__dict__ = dict((k.decode("ascii"), v) for k, v in obj.__dict__.items())


def fix_library(library):
    """Walk all library objects and decode __dict__ keys"""
    fix_object(library)
    for student in library.students:
            fix_object(student)
    for book in library.books:
            fix_object(book)
            for rental in book.rentals:
                    fix_object(rental)
```

But that's fragile and enough of a pain you should be looking for a better option.

1) Implement [`__getstate__`/`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) that maps datetime objects to a non-broken representation, for instance:

```
class Event(object):
    """Example class working around datetime pickling bug"""

    def __init__(self):
            self.date = datetime.date.today()

    def __getstate__(self):
            state = self.__dict__.copy()
            state["date"] = state["date"].toordinal()
            return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.date = datetime.date.fromordinal(self.date)
```

2) Don't use pickle at all. Along the lines of `__getstate__`/`__setstate__`, you can just implement `to_dict`/`from_dict` methods or similar in your classes for saving their content as json or some other plain format.

A final note, having a backreference to library in each object shouldn't be required.

Comment: I had narrowed it down to that datetime bug and I was reading a different bug report. Is there any way to get a better traceback from pickle when certain item can't be unpickled? The references to the library are just there for convenience of access. I think the __getstate__/__setstate__ solution is probably ideal.

Comment: Issues with pickle are indeed hard to debug, which along with the security problems are a good reason to serialise via a different mechanism where at all possible.

Comment: last question, which encoding would you use after implementing get/state state?

Comment: You shouldn't need one. From the dump given, all your attributes are ascii as expected, and the text content of the objects are type `unicode` not type `str` so will transfer fine.

Comment: Actually, from monkey patching the class, it seems you do need `encoding='utf-8'`. Also, a `is None` check for your date fields before trying to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Porting pickle py2 to py3 strings become bytes

The given `encoding='latin-1'` below, is ok.
Your Problem with `b''` are the result of using `encoding='bytes'`.
This will result in dict-keys being unpickled as bytes instead of as str.

The Problem data are the `datetime.date values '\x07á\x02\x10'`, starting at line **56** in `raw-data.pkl`.

It's a konwn Issue, as pointed already.
[Unpickling python2 datetime under python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805105/unpickling-python2-datetime-under-python3)
http://bugs.python.org/issue22005

For a workaround, I have patched `pickle.py` and got `unpickled object`, e.g.

> book.library.books[0].rentals[0].rental_date=2017-02-16

---

This will work for me:

```
t = pickle.loads(dumpstr, encoding="latin-1")
```

> **Output**:
>   <**main**.test object at 0xf7095fec>
>   t.__dict__={'x': 'test ¢'}
>   test ¢

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've updated the question to more accurately reflect  my problem

Comment: @user268: I will try it and come back with my results. Why don't you use `Protocol version 2`?

Comment: in case someone was worried about executing some random pickle data they downloaded from the internet

Comment: @user2682863: Added my Results to the Answer

Answer (score 1):

You should treat `pickle` data as specific to the (major) version of Python that created it.

(See [Gregory Smith's message w.r.t. issue 22005](http://bugs.python.org/issue22005#msg288821).)

The best way to get around this is to write a Python 2.7 program to read the pickled data, and write it out in a neutral format.

Taking a quick look at your actual data, it seems to me that an SQLite database is appropriate as an interchange format, since the `Book`s contain references to a `Library` and `RentalDetails`. You could create separate tables for each.